# How to delete folder with spaces on name from local and bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have folder named `-- backup_before_upgrade --` which unintentionally I uploaded to bitbucket.

‌‌Now I try to remove with `git rm -r --\ backup_before_upgrade\ --/`

but it says 
`error: unknown option 'backup_before_upgrade\ --/'`

As if `\` is not being taken in consideration to fill the empty space on the directory name.

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `git rm -r -- --\ backup_before_upgrade\ --/`

use `--` in order to indicate that following parameters starting with `-` are no options.

Answer (score 0):

You can separate arguments from options using `--`, so in your case

```
git rm -r -- "--\ backup_before_upgrade\ --"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
git rm -r -- '-- backup_before_upgrade --'
```